# GAE: An error occurred for the API request datastore_v3.Next()

Tags: google-app-engine

at a simple query with one filter like this:

```
PersistenceManager pm = PMF.getFactory().getPersistenceManager();
Key userKey = KeyFactory.createKey(User.class.getSimpleName(), Long.parseLong(userId));

Query query = pm.newQuery(Car.class);
query.setFilter("owner == ownerParam");
query.declareParameters(Key.class.getName() + " ownerParam");
List<Car> cars = (List<Car>) query.execute(userKey);
```

we get following error (when over approx. 300 entries)

> Caused by: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$UnknownException: An error occurred for the API request datastore_v3.Next().
>   at com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcStub$RpcCallbackDispatcher$1.runInContext(RpcStub.java:784)
>   at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:487)
>   at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:774)
>   at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$DoInTraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:751)
>   at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:342)
>   at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:334)
>   at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:484)
>   at com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcStub$RpcCallbackDispatcher.rpcFinished(RpcStub.java:824)
>   at com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcStub$RpcCallbackDispatcher.failure(RpcStub.java:815)
>   at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcClientInternalContext.runCallbacks(RpcClientInternalContext.java:953)
>   at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcClientInternalContext.finishRpcAndNotifyApp(RpcClientInternalContext.java:856)
>   at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.afterFinishingActiveRpc(RpcNetChannel.java:1195)
>   at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.finishRpc(RpcNetChannel.java:1031)
>   at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.handleResponse(RpcNetChannel.java:2520)
>   at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.messageReceived(RpcNetChannel.java:2277)
>   at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.access$2000(RpcNetChannel.java:155)
>   at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel$TransportCallback.receivedMessage(RpcNetChannel.java:3400)
>   at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcChannelTransportData$TransportCallback.receivedMessage(RpcChannelTransportData.java:626)
>   at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.wire.RpcBaseTransport.receivedMessage(RpcBaseTransport.java:430)
>   at com.google.net.eventmanager.AbstractFutureTask$Sync.innerRun(AbstractFutureTask.java:260)
>   at com.google.net.eventmanager.AbstractFutureTask.run(AbstractFutureTask.java:121)
>   at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl.runTask(EventManagerImpl.java:578)
>   at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl.internalRunWorkerLoop(EventManagerImpl.java:993)
>   at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl.runWorkerLoop(EventManagerImpl.java:875)
>   at com.google.net.eventmanager.WorkerThreadInfo.runWorkerLoop(WorkerThreadInfo.java:160)
>   at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl$WorkerThread.run(EventManagerImpl.java:1846)