# An error occurred for the API request datastore_v3.Next()

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm experiencing a similar issue to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16713563/gae-an-error-occurred-for-the-api-request-datastore-v3-next/45109617#45109617).

Any thoughts on how to resolve are appreciated.

The stack trace is:

```
*com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$UnknownException: An error occurred for the API request datastore_v3.Next(). at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl.statusException(ApiProxyImpl.java:657) at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$AsyncApiFuture.setRpcError(ApiProxyImpl.java:613) at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$AsyncApiFuture.failure(ApiProxyImpl.java:601) at com.google.apphosting.runtime.stubby.StubbyCallbackAdapter.failure(StubbyCallbackAdapter.java:25) at com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcStub$RpcCallbackDispatcher$1.runInContext(RpcStub.java:853) at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:460) at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:293) at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:319) at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:311) at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:457) at com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcStub$RpcCallbackDispatcher.runCallback(RpcStub.java:889) at com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcStub$RpcCallbackDispatcher.rpcFinished(RpcStub.java:899) at com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcStub$RpcCallbackDispatcher.failure(RpcStub.java:884) at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcClientInternalContext.runCallbacks(RpcClientInternalContext.java:1243) at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcClientInternalContext.finishRpcAndNotifyApp(RpcClientInternalContext.java:1137) at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.afterFinishingActiveRpc(RpcNetChannel.java:1701) at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.finishRpc(RpcNetChannel.java:1515) at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.handleResponse(RpcNetChannel.java:3373) at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.messageReceived(RpcNetChannel.java:3107) at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.access$3000(RpcNetChannel.java:185) at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel$TransportCallback.receivedMessage(RpcNetChannel.java:4321) at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcChannelTransportData$TransportCallback.receivedMessage(RpcChannelTransportData.java:688) at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.wire.RpcBaseTransport.receivedMessage(RpcBaseTransport.java:464) at com.google.apphosting.runtime.udrpc.UdrpcTransport$ClientAdapter.receivedMessage(UdrpcTransport.java:350) at com.google.apphosting.runtime.udrpc.UdrpcTransport.dispatchPacket(UdrpcTransport.java:196) at com.google.apphosting.runtime.udrpc.AbstractUdrpcTransport.readPackets(AbstractUdrpcTransport.java:202) at com.google.apphosting.runtime.udrpc.AbstractUdrpcTransport.access$000(AbstractUdrpcTransport.java:30) at com.google.apphosting.runtime.udrpc.AbstractUdrpcTransport$1.run(AbstractUdrpcTransport.java:57) at com.google.net.eventmanager.AbstractFutureTask$Sync.innerRun(AbstractFutureTask.java:260) at com.google.net.eventmanager.AbstractFutureTask.run(AbstractFutureTask.java:121) at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl.runTask(EventManagerImpl.java:594) at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl.internalRunWorkerLoop(EventManagerImpl.java:1012) at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl.runWorkerLoop(EventManagerImpl.java:892) at com.google.net.eventmanager.WorkerThreadInfo.runWorkerLoop(WorkerThreadInfo.java:161) at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl$WorkerThread.run(EventManagerImpl.java:1877)

Uncaught exception from servlet com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$UnknownException: An error occurred for the API request datastore_v3.Next(). at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl.statusException(ApiProxyImpl.java:657) at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$AsyncApiFuture.setRpcError(ApiProxyImpl.java:613) at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$AsyncApiFuture.failure(ApiProxyImpl.java:601) at com.google.apphosting.runtime.stubby.StubbyCallbackAdapter.failure(StubbyCallbackAdapter.java:25) at com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcStub$RpcCallbackDispatcher$1.runInContext(RpcStub.java:853) at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:460) at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:293) at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:319) at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:311) at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:457) at com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcStub$RpcCallbackDispatcher.runCallback(RpcStub.java:889) at com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcStub$RpcCallbackDispatcher.rpcFinished(RpcStub.java:899) at com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcStub$RpcCallbackDispatcher.failure(RpcStub.java:884) at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcClientInternalContext.runCallbacks(RpcClientInternalContext.java:1243) at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcClientInternalContext.finishRpcAndNotifyApp(RpcClientInternalContext.java:1137) at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.afterFinishingActiveRpc(RpcNetChannel.java:1701) at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.finishRpc(RpcNetChannel.java:1515) at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.handleResponse(RpcNetChannel.java:3373) at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.messageReceived(RpcNetChannel.java:3107) at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.access$3000(RpcNetChannel.java:185) at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel$TransportCallback.receivedMessage(RpcNetChannel.java:4321) at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcChannelTransportData$TransportCallback.receivedMessage(RpcChannelTransportData.java:688) at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.wire.RpcBaseTransport.receivedMessage(RpcBaseTransport.java:464) at com.google.apphosting.runtime.udrpc.UdrpcTransport$ClientAdapter.receivedMessage(UdrpcTransport.java:350) at com.google.apphosting.runtime.udrpc.UdrpcTransport.dispatchPacket(UdrpcTransport.java:196) at com.google.apphosting.runtime.udrpc.AbstractUdrpcTransport.readPackets(AbstractUdrpcTransport.java:202) at com.google.apphosting.runtime.udrpc.AbstractUdrpcTransport.access$000(AbstractUdrpcTransport.java:30) at com.google.apphosting.runtime.udrpc.AbstractUdrpcTransport$1.run(AbstractUdrpcTransport.java:57) at com.google.net.eventmanager.AbstractFutureTask$Sync.innerRun(AbstractFutureTask.java:260) at com.google.net.eventmanager.AbstractFutureTask.run(AbstractFutureTask.java:121) at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl.runTask(EventManagerImpl.java:594) at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl.internalRunWorkerLoop(EventManagerImpl.java:1012) at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl.runWorkerLoop(EventManagerImpl.java:892) at com.google.net.eventmanager.WorkerThreadInfo.runWorkerLoop(WorkerThreadInfo.java:161) at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl$WorkerThread.run(EventManagerImpl.java:1877)*
```